# SQL Server Code Reuse Via Stored Procedures - Good or Bad Practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I'm currently considering design options for a reporting application based on an existing dataset.

There are several clear opportunities for code reuse given that many of the reports need to use the same base data set (Edited).

The tempation is to create some base stored procedure that I can reuse throughout this system, however, the contract I was on 6 months ago or so showed me what the down side of this practice - multiple layers of - large stored procedure calls returning subsets of data in, making it very very difficult to workout what was going on, debug and test.

I'm these days of the opinion that code reuse does not necessarily enhance maintainability in database design.

I'm looking for some insight on this from a more experienced SQL Server dev than myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I'm these days of the opinion that code reuse does not necessarily enhance maintainability in database design." is the main question, the rest of the text is for context.

Comment: Is there any reason for the specific limitation in the title of stored procedures? These are not the only mechanism for code reuse.

Comment: Not really. I understand that there's several ways to achieve code reuse.

Comment: For example - I have a stored procedure that returns a specific data set (report 1) showing a customers account history. The new data set (report 2) I need, is very similar, but only needs a subset of this data. To pull all of the data using the original report is inefficient, as I don't need all of the result set. In addition, if that original report is changed, it may break my new report. On top of this, if a new developer wants to understand report 2, he must also understand report 1. Where several sprocs / views/ functions are combined to create new data sets, this becomes less manageable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Disclaimer: This isn't a "don't use stored procedures - think of the children!" post, and I'm not aiming to ignite a flame-war. I'm just suggesting code re-use is easier and possibly more suited to certain situations and platforms than others.*

Code Reuse as a concept does generally improve a codebase. You keep things [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and begin to form a layer of common functionality to solve common problems in the same way.

However like anything, one can get it wrong (with power comes responsibility blah blah blah).

It's relatively simple in most modern programming languages to reuse code, either by writing functions, or even creating whole frameworks that can be used again and again. However, in T-SQL it's tricksy because you have less options.  Stored procedures can do it, but you've seen how awkward they can be.

My personal preference is to keep business logic out of the database. That means I don't use views, UDFs, sprocs etc (unless after performance profiling we think we can speed something up using these techniques) and instead keep it in my application code. This often causes thoughts of a "business logic layer" but there are various flavours of that so it's probably a misnomer. It's certainly not code directly behind UI button click handlers and so on, though.

I aim to limit the database to storing and retrieving data, because that's what they're reaaally good at. We all know how clunky and outdated T-SQL can be as a language (think exception-handling, deployment, cursors etc). Being database-agnostic is completely impossible if your application is written into the database itself, and you also can't scale your application, because the database *is* the application. If you have that business logic in application code, it can be scaled out much more easily.

In this case the "business logic" is the queries and transformations used to generate your reports, and I would investigate how it might be possible to reuse code in your reporting tool/code, before considering other options.

Comment: I agree with everything you say. It sounds though like you prefer inline sql over stored procedures? Performance would suffer too much in my case for this. Also, I especially agree with keeping business logic out of a database - however the trade off here is that transformations in the business logic layer are not as efficient, and may require multiple round trips to the database. This means that inevitably business logic does end up in the database in my applications. I also think databases are great places to enforce business rules via constraints.

Comment: I'm not getting into a "sprocs aren't that much faster" argument here, but I do suggest you measure the performance of both before you assume that. Once upon a time it was true, but as a profession we need to question those old assumptions. Query optimisers and query plan caching in recent years practically negate any benefit of compiled queries/sprocs. Transformations are also unlikely to be much faster, because you can spoil the database engine's ability to plan efficiently. Also, constraints aren't business rules - they're data integrity rules.

Comment: I.e. it's horses for courses - just be sure you've measured and proven your approach rather than making assumptions. For everyone that can prove what I've said above, there'll be someone who disagrees and can prove it, too. You need to *prove* these assumptions and draw your own conclusions for your own particular situation and requirements.

Comment: I won't dispute anything you say there. Bench marking does need to be done in each context where performance is key. I like to keep the separation of data and process (hopefully that makes sense). If I want a data set, I feel that is a database concern, and should be handled by the database. I'm not saying there's not downsides to this - my question relates to the fact that there are obvious downsides to this. I think I have to keep my focus on code management within the database here, though I understand your point completley.

Comment: I'm going to mark this the answer, as although it does not give a perfect resolution (it seems that none exists), it does address the concern in my question - If code manageability and reuse in database design is a primary concern, avoid it altogether, even if the cost is performance.

Comment: "constraints aren't business rules - they're data integrity rules" -- oh, man. A row is a business rule!

Comment: Constraints are there to keep your data straight. They are a last-resort, and are not the correct place to enforce the business rule. A business rule requiring an order reference be unique should not be implemented by catching `SqlException`, it should be implemented by checking in the database for the order reference, and informing the user if you find it exists with a helpful message. The DB constraint is just a last resort to prevent bugs/forgetfulness spoiling the integrity of your data.

Comment: In the first place it's a myth that database doesn't scale. T-SQL scales faster when written by good developers having knowledge of SQL server. If one keeps SQL in application code how would one process data? C# or Java is not designed to process data. It's SQL (a set based language) which is designed to use the optimizer and if you are processing data using c# or java construct you are defeating the purpose of using a database. Constraints are business rules and must be in the database. Why? Because db kernel code is far smarter than you to handle data.

Answer (score 2):

Code reuse in TSQL needs to be taken on a case by case base. You need to get into the habit of checking the execution plans for all the queries you write to determine whether the plan looks reasonable or not.

Joining Views onto Views can work fine or can cause inefficiencies depending on their definition.

Inline Table Valued Functions can be an extremely good way of reusing code. They avoid possible predicate pushing issues with Views and as they get expanded out by the query optimiser they allow you to apply filters to the results more efficiently than trying to do the same thing with a multi statement TVF or a stored procedure resultset.

Answer (score 1):

The primary purpose of code reuse, IMO, is to break monolithic programs up into more easily understood and more easily maintained pieces. The division of labor must not be idiosyncratic -- one man's personal quirky idea of order. The art of constructing a library of helper functions is in very large part a social art -- you must define an intelligible API that is consistent in its approach. You don't want the coders who follow after you to be cursing you in absentia. You want them to be thanking you for the clarity and utility of your design.

@Neil Barnwell: I see no problem with building business-rules into the database.  Triggers and stored procs can perform this role just as well if not better than a middle tier or client code.  Of course, you must have programmers who have mastered the programming language in the database, T-SQL or PL/SQL or whatever it happens to be.

Comment: I've seen and done both and I know that for any reasonable-sized professional enterprise application, it always turns out to have been a massive mistake further down the line. There are so many reasons that I'm not going to list them here. It's a religious war, which means by definition it can never be won. As long as there are no assumptions, and scientific conclusions are drawn from real observations, then one should do the right thing given one's circumstances.

Comment: Maybe you might consider being a bit more conservative with comments such as "Triggers and stored procs can perform this role just as well **if not better** than a middle tier or client code" (emphasis mine). You are comparing the archaic T-SQL favourably to modern, more powerful languages such as Java or C#, which is very hard to prove.

Comment: @Neil. I said enforcing rules in the DB can be just as good as or better than doing so in another tier. You say enforcing rules in the database is a "massive mistake" and then tell me that *I* should be more conservative in my pronouncements! T-SQL and PL/SQL have been tightly integrated with set operations for decades. OO languages have been playing catchup in this particular respect. I use C# all the time and love it; certainly not panning OO. Just saying that it can be overkill for enforcing business rules when mere conditional logic and a loop will usually suffice.